# Two interpretations of significant negative intercept: which is correct?

Tags: interpretation, intercept

I applied a linear mixed model on binomial data. In short, I have 2 binomial independent variables: Prime (DO or PO) and Language (English L1 and English L2), and my dependent variable is DO use (DO or PO response is possible, but for my analysis I use the proportion of DO responses).

This is my output:

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  

(Intercept) -2.20426    0.26103  -8.445  < 2e-16 ***

fPrime1     -0.60838    0.07525  -8.085 6.23e-16 ***

fLanguage1   1.12670    0.22185   5.079 3.80e-07 ***
```

My reference level would be PO prime for English L1. I see I have a (significant) negative intercept, but do I have to interpret this regarding the reference level, or overall? In other words, does this mean that English L1 participants with a PO prime prefer a PO response (because of negative intercept) over a DO response, or does this mean that overall, in general, participants prefer the use of PO?

I thought I had to interpret this regarding the reference level, but I found some studies similar to my study just applying the overall interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

The intercept is the parameter for when all the independent variables are 0.  If you coded the independent variables so that the reference group is 0, then that is what it is referring to.

Comment: But how can it then be that some researchers report this for example: "The significant negative intercept indicates that there
was an **overall bias** towards of-genitives: The chance of
an S-genitive in the of-genitive condition was significantly
below 50% when the head nouns had different meanings.
The percentage of S-genitives in this condition (26%) increased
to 32% when an S-genitive prime was presented,
resulting in a 6% effect of between-language priming that
was marginally significant".

Comment: In case this is not very clear, this is the original article: http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0010027713000334/1-s2.0-S0010027713000334-main.pdf?_tid=311ef8da-b554-11e5-9046-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1452181071_d25c858761187334038c03af20817cf3

Comment: When all other variables are zero (whatever that means substantively) then the probability of seeing a 1 rather than a 0 is about 0.1 because `plogis(-2.20426)` is 0.09936859. Does this help?

Comment: That could be correct, depending on how the model is parameterized.